# Substituir texto com srt_replace usando aspas duplas

Tags: php

Estou tentando usar o str_replace para alterar uma parte do código,

```
$mudali = "li id=\"cabeca{$raiz}\" class=\"cabeca\"";
$mudali2 = "li id=\"pes{$raiz}\" class=\"pes\"";

echo $mudali; // resultado li id="cabeca-geral" class="cabeca"
echo $mudali2; // resultado li id="pes-geral" class="pes"

$rodape = str_replace($mudali, $mudali2, $rodape);
```

Mas não funciona, porém se retiro tudo até as aspas duplas, o código funciona

```
$mudali = "cabeca{$raiz}";
$mudali2 = "pes{$raiz}";

echo $mudali; // resultado cabeca-geral
echo $mudali2; // resultado pes-geral

$rodape = str_replace($mudali, $mudali2, $rodape);
```

Alguém sabe como arrumar?

Comment: Mas o que exatamente você quer alterar? o id? a classe? ambos?

Comment: Gostaria de alterar o id e o class, mas, apesar do echo gerar o texto exato do que quero substituir, com o str_replace não vai cara, só funciona se tiro as aspas duplas

Comment: Pode dar echo na variável rodapé e nos mostrar também?

Comment: Já tentou utilizar aspas simples em suas variáveis mudali e mudali2? desse maneira não será necessária a utilização de "\" antes da aspas duplas.

Comment: O echo do rodapé é id="<li id="cabeca-geral" class="cabeca"><p>Conheça as principais ....

Comment: Vinicius mudei para aspas simples, continua não funcionando, e tive de tirar a variável de dentro da string, mudei para $mudali = 'cabeca' . $raiz . '" class="cabeca"';

Comment: Não tem como usar uma string com aspas duplas no str_replace?

Comment: O funcionamento do str_replace é simples, no primeiro parâmetro, procura o segundo, se encontrar, coloca o terceiro no do valor igual ao segundo. Repense em como utilizar isso para resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Eu consigo alterar o texto se mudo o texto sem as aspas duplas, por exemplo, só o nome da id cabeca-geral, mas se procuro o texto com id="cabeca-geral' ele não faz nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente tem alguma diferença em `$rodape` que está fazendo a substituição falhar. Espaços, tabs, acentos, alguma coisa assim. Sugiro reescrever todos esses trechos, onde `$rodape` é criado, tomando cuidado. Para debugar a possível diferença:

```
print "HEX1:" . bin2hex($mudali);
print "HEX2:" . bin2hex($rodape);
```

Comment: Mas no string que tenho, tem trechos que o código é parecido, dai altera lá também e eu queria mudar só no id

Comment: Nesse caso a sua solução é a mais correta. Daí descobrir o que está impedindo o replace de funcionar. Modificando a resposta.